# Wrapping the classList API to add/remove array of classes

Tags: javascript, meta-programming

I've written a function that wraps the [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) API, allowing you to pass an array of classes to add/remove, or the variable arguments already supported by `classList`.

The methods are the following:

```
var flatten = function(array) {
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], array);
};

var classMethod = function(method) {
    return function(element /*, classes... */) {
        return flatten(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)).forEach(function(klass) {
            element.classList[method](klass);
        });
    }
};

var addClass = classMethod('add');
var removeClass = classMethod('remove');
```

Usage:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.box');

addClass(elem,     'class1');
addClass(elem,     'class2', 'class3');
addClass(elem,    ['class2', 'class3']);

removeClass(elem,  'class1');
removeClass(elem,  'class2', 'class3');
removeClass(elem, ['class2', 'class3']);
```

I'm wondering if there's some better way to implement this function, say without using the `forEach` call and instead using [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), but I get a *TypeError: Illegal invocation* when trying to refactor this into, say:

```
var classMethod = function(method) {
    return function(element /*, classes... */) {
        element.classList[method].apply(element, flatten(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)));
    }
};
```

Is it possible to write this more succinctly, whilst keeping all of the use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question,

I've been looking at this for a while, I dont think there is a more succinct way. I've been playing with reconstructing `className` from the `add` or `remove` function calls but it became a less succinct and terrible hack.

The core reason for that is default JS does not have enough convenience methods for arrays. If you were open to use something like LoDash, you could do this:

```
var addClass = function addClass(element /*, classes... */){
  element.className = _.uniq( element.className.split(' ').concat( _.flatten( _.rest( arguments ) ) ) ).join(' ');  
};

var removeClass = function removeClass(element /*, classes... */){
  element.className = _.difference( element.className.split(' '),  _.flatten( _.rest( arguments ) )  ).join(' ');
};
```

Other than that I really like your code; proper naming, indenting, size of functions, etc.

Update on *illegal invocation*, you are passing `element` as this to a function that is attached to `classList`, if you pass `classList`, then there will be no exception.

```
var classMethod = function(method) {
    return function(element /*, classes... */) {
        var classList = element.classList;
        element.classList[method].apply(classList,flatten(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)));
    };
};
```

And then that works.. My mind is still boggling at that, but there you go.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on the *Illegal invocation*? To be honest I don't really know why the refactor I tried didn't work as expected.

Comment: Found it, updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Indeed, I didn't realise that you could (and in this case needed to) `apply` with a property of an object. So we can also do `apply(element.classList)`, but I think I prefer your idea of caching it in a variable. Note that we can simplify this a little further by removing `element.` from the start of of the call to `apply` (we can just use the cached value). Thanks! :-)